# Memory leak risk in JavaScript closures

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, cross-browser, closures

***Solved***

There's a lot of contradictory information on the web, regarding this subject. Thanks to @John, I managed to work out that the closures (as used below) aren't the cause of memory leaks, and that -even in IE8- they're not that common as people claim. In fact there was only 1 leak that occurred in my code, which proved not that difficult to fix.

From now on, my answer to this question will be:
*AFAIK, the only time IE8 leaks, is when events are attached/handlers are set on the global object. (`window.onload`,`window.onbeforeunload`,...). To get around this, see my answer below.*

---

***HUGE* UPDATE:**

I'm completly lost now... After some time digging through articles and tuts both old and new, I'm left with at least one humongous contradiction. While one of *THE* JavaScript Guru's (Douglas Crockford) says:

> Since IE is unable to do its job and reclaim the cycles, it falls on us to do it. If we explicitly break the cycles, then IE will be able to reclaim the memory. According to Microsoft, closures are the cause of memory leaks. This is of course deeply wrong, but it leads to Microsoft giving very bad advice to programmers on how to cope with Microsoft's bugs. It turns out that it is easy to break the cycles on the DOM side. It is virtually impossible to break them on the JScript side.

And as @freakish pointed out that my snippets below are similar to jQuery's internal workings I felt pretty secure about my solution not causing memory leaks. At the same time I found [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448(v=vs.85).aspx), where the section `Circular References with Closures` was of particular interest to me. The figure below is pretty much a schematic representation of how my code works, isn't it:

[image: Circular References with Closures]

The only difference being that I have the common sense of not attaching my event listeners to the elements themselves. 
All the same *Douggie* is quite unequivocal: closures are not the source of mem-leaks in IE. This contradiction leaves me clueless as to who's right.

I've also found out that the leak issue isn't completely solved in IE9 either (can't find the link ATM).

*One last thing*: I've also come to learn that IE manages the DOM outside the JScript engine, which puts me in a spot of bother when I change the children of a `<select>` element, based on an ajax request:

```
function changeSeason(e)
{
    var xhr,sendVal,targetID;
    e = e || window.event;//(IE...
    targetID = this.id.replace(/commonSourceFragment/,'commonTargetFragment');//fooHomeSelect -> barHomeSelect
    sendVal = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML.trim().substring(0,1);
    xhr = prepareAjax(false,(function(t)
    {
        return function()
        {
            reusableCallback.apply(this,[t]);
        }
    })(document.getElementById(targetID)),'/index/ajax');
    xhr({data:{newSelect:sendVal}});
}

function reusableCallback(elem)
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        elem.innerHTML = '<option>' + data.theArray.join('</option><option>') + '</option>';
    }
}
```

If IE really does manage the DOM as though the JScript engine weren't there, what are the odds that the option elements aren't deallocated using this code?
 I've deliberately added this snippet as an example, because in this case I'm passing variables that are part of the closure scope as an argument to a global function. I couldn't find any documentation on this practice, but based on the documentation provided by Miscrosoft, it should break any circular references that might occur, doesn't it?

---

---

**Warning**: lengthy question... (*sorry*)

I've written a couple of fairly large JavaScripts to make Ajax calls in my web application. in order to avoid tons of callbacks and events, I'm taking full advantage of event delegation and closures. Now I've written a function that has me wondering as to possible memory leaks. Though I know IE > 8 deals with closures a lot better then its predecessors, it is company policy to support IE 8 all the same.

Below I've provided an example of what I'm on about, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6xsRv/) you can find a similar example, though it doesn't use ajax, but a setTimeout, the result is pretty much the same. (You can, of course skip the code below, to the question itself)

The code I have in mind is this:

```
function prepareAjax(callback,method,url)
{
    method = method || 'POST';
    callback = callback || success;//a default CB, just logs/alerts the response
    url = url || getUrl();//makes default url /currentController/ajax
    var xhr = createXHRObject();//try{}catch etc...
    xhr.open(method,url,true);
    xhr.setRequestMethod('X-Requested-with','XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','*/*');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        callback.apply(xhr);
    }
    return function(data)
    {
        //do some checks on data before sending: data.hasOwnProperty('user') etc...
        xhr.send(data);
    }
}
```

All pretty straight-forward stuff, except for the `onreadystatechange` callback. I noticed some issues with IE when binding the handler directly: `xhr.onreadystatechange = callback;`, hence the anonymous function. Don't know why, but I found this to be the easiest way to make it work.

As I said, I'm using a lot of event delegation, so you can imagine it may prove useful to have access to the actual element/event that fired the ajax call. So I have some event handlers that look like this:

```
function handleClick(e)
{
    var target,parent,data,i;
    e = e || window.event;
    target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input' && target.className !== 'delegateMe')
    {
        return true;
    }
    parent = target;
    while(parent.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr')
    {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
    data = {};
    for(i=0;i<parent.cells;i++)
    {
        data[parent.cells[i].className] = parent.cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
    //data looks something like {name:'Bar',firstName:'Foo',title:'Mr.'}
    i = prepareAjax((function(t)
    {
        return function()
        {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
            {
                //check responseText and, if ok:
                t.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
            }
        }
    })(target));
    i(data);
}
```

As you can see, the `onreadystatechange` callback is the return value of a function, that provides the reference to the `target` element when the callback is called. Thanks to event delegation, I no longer have to worry about events that might be bound to that element, when I decide to remove it from the DOM (which I do sometimes). 
To my mind, however, the call object of the callback function might prove too much for IE's JScript engine and its garbage collector:

> Event ==> handler ==> prepareAjax is a pretty normal call sequence, but the callback argument:
>
> [anon. func (argument t = target) returns anon. F (has access to t which in turn refs back to target)]
>    ===> passed to a anon callback function, called using .apply method to the xhr object, in turn a *private* variable to the prepareAjax function

I've tested this "construction" in FF and chrome. It works just fine there, but would this kind of callstack of closure upon closure upon closure, on each occasion passing a reference to a DOM element be an issue in IE (especially versions prior to IE9)?

---

No, I'm not going to use jQuery or other libs. I like pure JS, and want to know as much as I can about this seriously underrated language. The code snippets are not actual copy-paste examples, but provide, IMO, a good representation of how I'm using delegation, closures and callbacks throughout my script. So if some syntax isn't quite right, feel free to correct it, but that's not what this question is about, of course.

Comment: I don't know why `xhr.onreadystatechange=callback` does not work for you. Interesting. But actually this part shouldn't matter at all, the memory leak is the most interesting thing. I've never seen such behaviour, although I didn't work with IE<9 for quite a while.

Comment: BTW: You don't have to use jQuery, but you may look at its source code. :) I did and it seems, that they are not doing anything different then you are. It shouldn't give memory leaks. Are you sure, that you are not holding a reference to the `xhr` somewhere? Or to `prepareAjax` result?

Comment: @freakish: I don't expect the `xhr.onreadystatechange=callback` to be the cause of the memory issues (if any). I mentioned it because I, too, find it strange behaviour on IE's part. But I've long given up hope of IE behaving logically. According to you, is this code likely to cause memory issues, that's what I'm worried about

Comment: :) I often look at how jQuery does things, too. No, I don't use any global variables, so there shouldn't be any references to `xhr` after the success callback has returned. In which case, I can assume there won't be any memory leaks. Thanks! post this as an answer and I'll accept it asap

Comment: No, no, this is not answering your question at all. This wouldn't be fair. I don't think that `.onreadystatechange` declaration is an issue. It shouldn't be. But then again this is IE after all. :)

Comment: Neither do I. I wanted to know if there would be a chance of memory issues using closers to pass references to DOM elements. I can't recall where or when, but you know how you get that gut feeling or vague recollection that some code might cause trouble? That's why I posted this question. On the callback: `xhr.onreadystatechange = callback` works in IE, but only once, even weirder. I can only assume the function is bound to xhr locally, requiring a local function. You gave the answer to the title question, so this issue is resolved, as far as I'm concerned. I have some Ideas on IE, but 0 chars

Comment: You shouldn't worry about DOM memory deallocation. Problem with IE's circular references is really difficult for me to understand, to be honest. :) But what about these Crockford's words? `It turns out that it is easy to break the cycles on the DOM side` and `If we explicitly break the cycles, then IE will be able to reclaim the memory`. Have you tried (somewhat pathological idea, but might work) removing the button and recreating it and its click handler (after AJAX response)? Or am I totally lost here? :)

Comment: I've thought about that, too. The problem(s) I have there is that I'm using event delegation, so the memory issues aren't down to event listeners, that outlive the DOM elements, they're attached to the `document.body`. The other thing is that IE doesn't manage the DOM via the JScript engine, so there really isn't any way of completely removing an element in IE (found that info somewhere in the links, in the MSDN page I mentioned)

Comment: Hmm, after reading the link you gave us I think that also you may try "rebinding" the handler, i.e. unbind it and bind again (you can use it on `body`) and also put unbinding mechanism on `onUnload` event. As for IE's element removal mechanism I have only one thing to say: OMFG! :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I used to work with the ex-program manager for JavaScript within Microsoft, on a non-browser EcmaScript (err.. JScr... JavaScript) project.  We had some lengthy discussions about closures.  In the end, the point is that they are harder to GC, not impossible.  I'd have to read DC's discussion of how MS is 'wrong' that closures cause memory leaks -- for in IE's older implementations, closures were certainly problematic, because they were very hard to garbage collect **with the MS implementation**.  I find it strange that a Yahoo guy would try to tell the MS architects that a known issue with their code was somewhere else.  As much as I appreciate his work, I don't see what basis he had there.

Remember, the article you reference above refers to IE6, as IE7 was still under heavy development at the time of its writing.

As an aside -- thank god, IE6 is dead (don't make my dig up the funeral pictures).  Although, don't forget its legacy... I've yet to see anyone make a credible argument that it wasn't the finest browser in the world on day 1 of its release -- the problem was that they won the browser war.  And so, in what amounts to one of the larger blunders of their history -- they fired the team afterwards and it sat stagnant for nearly 5 years.  The IE team was down to 4 or 5 guys doing bug fixes for years, creating a huge brain drain and falling behind the curve dramatically.  By the time they rehired the team and realized where they were, they were years behind because of the added cruft of dealing with a monolothic codebase that nobody really understood anymore.  That's my perspective as an internal in the company, but not directly tied to that team.

Remember too, IE never optimized for closures because there was no ProtoypeJS (heck, there was no Rails), and jQuery was barely a glimmer in Resig's head.

At the time of the writing, they were also still targeting machines with 256 megs of RAM, which also hadn't been end-of-life'd.

I thought it only fair to hand you this history lesson, after making me read your entire book of a question.

In the end, my point is that you're referencing material which is hugely dated.  Yes, avoid closures in IE6, as they cause memory leaks -- but what didn't in IE6?

In the end, it is a problem that MS has addressed and continues to address.  You're going to make some level of closures, that was the case, even back then.

I know that they did heavy work in this area around IE8 (as my unmentionable project used the non-at-the-time standard JavaScript engine), and that work has continued into IE9/10.  StatCounter (http://gs.statcounter.com/) suggests that IE7 is down to a 1.5% market share, down from 6% a year ago, and in developing 'new' sites, IE7 becomes less and less relevant.  You can also develop for NetScape 2.0, which introduced JavaScript support, but that would be only slightly less silly.

Really... Don't try to over-optimize for the sake of an engine which doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: +1 for numerous chuckles while reading your answer. I have no intention of over-optimizing for old engines. True, the DC link is very much outdated. But honestly, memory leaks are often talked about, but it is incredibly hard pinpoint what is causing them, why and where. The MSDN link I provided talks about circular references to DOM objects, which comes very close to what I'm doing, couple that to having no real control over the DOM elements' management, and I get curious/nervous. I'm looking for a _definitive _ answer to: "What causes mem issues, what browser, why and how to avoid them?"

Comment: The short answer is Flash.

The longer answer you've hit on the head... you have no access to the garbage collection.  The memory management really depends on the vendor of the browser, and will really be a closed-box unless you have access to (and are willing to trace) the source code, since individual browsers don't really give you this access.  The circular references in the MSDN article reflect an earlier implementation of how IE deals with objects (I say IE, because it is a combination of the DOM+script), and I would doubt it holds true today.

Comment: Any definitive answer will be outdated as soon as the developers realize there is a problem and take the time to fix it.  Plus, new features will add new leaks (Canvas).  There are certainly things that will always cause memory leaks (for instance, persisting things in global scope JS or adding a bunch of rendered objects to the DOM).  That being said, the question is vague enough to not have a definitive answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: Flash: NO, MSDN: it's from 2005, fair enough. But it wasn't archived until 2011, and it links to a knowledge base article that was last updated in 2007. Vague: perhaps, I'm not too good at explaining myself. Not being a native speaker doesn't help, of course

Comment: Memory leaks almost always exist in advanced code.  That is, the allocation of memory without an deallocation.  You'll find instances of this in just about everything.  Heck, I even have to reboot my mac once every other month.  Trying to remove them entirely is like trying to ship bug-free code.  A lofty goal, but one you'll never really accomplish.  You squash what you can, make sure you don't wipe anyone's hard drive, and fix more in the next release.

Comment: Btw, if you missed it -- my Flash reference was an example of how to create a memory leak.  ; )

Comment: I get your saying, and agree with you up to a point. Blame it on OCD, but I want, _need_ to know, even, what causes mem. leaks in the main JS implementations, and if my code might cause them. If so, what I could try to reduce them or (Utopia Triumphans) get rid of them all together. And yes, I missed the Flash reference. In my defence: it's been over 5 years since I've used flash, or even known of someone using it, for that matter.

Comment: Again, it is too broad of a question... You can't do it in C#, you certainly can't do it in C++, what makes you think that you can do it in JS?  : )  Especially when each version and minor version will change (sometimes dramatically) the problem set.  Most browsers will have special tools for you to check things.  In fact, I just found this for IE:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gpde/archive/2009/08/03/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2.aspx  Notice that it suggests that the circular object problem is completely mitigated.  So... all of the old information you reference above is antiquated.

Comment: thanks for the link. Again, I wasn't trying to be stubborn (well, I was - I wanted to _know_ with 100% certainty). I'll install the leak detector at work tomorrow and get cracking!

Answer (score 4):

Right, after spending some time with that `IEJSLeaksDetector` tool, I've found out that the things I talked about in my original question ***DO NOT CAUSE MEM LEAKS***. However, there was 1 leak that did pop up. Thankfully, I've managed to find a solution:

I have a main script, and at the bottom, there's an old school:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //do some stuff, get URI, and call:
    this['_init' + uri[0].ucFirst()](uri);//calls func like _initController
    //ucFirst is an augmentation of the String.prototype
}
```

This causes a leak in IE8, That I couldn't fix with a `window.onbeforeunload` handler. It seems you have to avoid binding the handler to the global object. The solution lies in closures and event listeners, it's a bit of a faff, but here's what I ended up doing:

```
(function(go)
{//use closure to avoid leaking issue in IE
    function loader()
    {
        var uri = location.href.split(location.host)[1].split('/');
        //do stuff
        if (this['_init' + uri[0].ucFirst()] instanceof Function)
        {
            this['_init' + uri[0].ucFirst()](uri);
        }
        if (!(this.removeEventListener))
        {
            this.detachEvent('onload',loader);//(fix leak?
            return null;
        }
        this.removeEventListener('load',loader,false);
    }
    if (!(go.addEventListener))
    {
        go.attachEvent('onload',loader);//(IE...
    }
    else
    {
        go.addEventListener('load',loader,false);
    }
})(window);
```

That way, the (on)load event is unbound just before the `window.load` handler returns, according to the IEJSLeaksDetector tool, there are *NO* leaks in my application. I'm happy with that. I hope this snippet is of some use to one of you - if someone has suggestions to improve this approach, don't hesitate to do so!

Cheers, and thanks to all of you who went through the trouble of reading and trying my dribble above!

---

PS: in case someone cares, here's the ucFirst String method:

```
if (!(String.prototype.ucFirst))
{
    String.prototype.ucFirst = function()
    {
        "use strict";
        return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
    };
}
```

Comment: Is the IEJSLeaksDetector useful for IE 8, or only for versions earlier than IE 8?

Comment: It's useful for IE8, given that is was developed along side IE8 (and still under active development when IE8 was released)\