# onresize event not firing when accessing window width

Tags: javascript, onresize

I've attached the onresize listener to the body tag just fine but when I change my code to access the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` my resize event only works one time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMsg()
    {
        document.write((window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) * 100 + "%");
    }
</script>
<body onresize="showMsg()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense, have you tried checking the source of your page `after` the function has returned? there's no more body tag is there - with it goes your event listener (or could still be in memory, dangling uselessly). 
Try attaching it to `window`.

```
window.onresize = function()
{
    document.write((this.innerWidth/this.innerHeight)*100+'%');
};
```

Now in older version of a formerly very popular browser this (attaching event listeners to the window object) causes memory leaks. The window object is never really destroyed [more info here if you need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186750/memory-leak-risk-in-javascript-closures).

how to solve the mem issue?

```
(function(win)
{
    win.onresize = function()
    {
        document.write((this.innerWidth/this.innerHeight)*100+'%');
    };
    if (win.attachEvent)
    {
        win.attachEvent('onbeforeunload',(function(self)
        {
            return function freeMem()
            {
                self.onresize = null;
                self.detachEvent('onbeforeunload',freeMem);
            };
        })(win));
        return;
    }
    win.addEventListener('beforeunload',(functio(self)
    {
        return function freeMem()
        {
            self.onresize = null;
            self.removeEventListener('beforeUnload',freeMem,false);
        };
    })(win),false);
})(this);//this points to current window
```

I know, looks awful, but I've tested this and it does the trick - Thanks for that IE. Strictly speaking the closures passing `win` to `self` could be omitted, but I keep it in there to be absolutely sure, as soon as the `onbeforeunload` event fires, and the handler returns *all* functions and refernces go out of scope, so the GC's have no reason *not* to free the memory. 
It's overkill in most situations, but just in case someone cares, I decided to post it here... :-P