# How to manually garbage collect JavaScript closure

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, closures

We're all aware that closure sticks around in memory for our benefit. Because of existing or intentional created reference, it can not be garbage-collected. My question here is what if I want it to be GC'd, how do I go about doing that?
This is actually one of the interview questions I got recently.Thanks a bunch!

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619701/garbage-collection-in-javascript-closures)

Comment: `var yourClosureRef = null;` should do it.