# Updating page with "document.write" removes formatting

Tags: javascript, html

I've been wondering if there is a way to prevent my functions hiding any current text/formatting.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#F5F0EB";
var page = 0
function flip(){
document.write(page);
page++;
}
</script>
<input type=button value="Next" onClick="flip()">
</body>
```

When I press the button I lose the coloured background and the text appears. Is there a way to make the background stay and the text appear?

Comment: Don't use `document.write`

Comment: What should I be using in this situation?

Comment: `document.write` clears the DOM once the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by not using `document.write()`. [MDN explains it clearly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write#Notes):

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling
>   document.open() will automatically perform a document.open call.

And about `document.open()` [it says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.open#Notes):

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it.

What you *should* be doing, is manipulate nodes in the DOM. For example, you could change the inner HTML of the body:

```
document.body.innerHTML += page;
```

Alternatively, you could create a text node and append it:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode(page);
document.body.appendChild(textNode);
```

In both cases, the current document is not flushed, it is only modified.

Comment: +1, removed the examples quote as you didn't add the example... :)

Comment: @gdoron Thanks, looks like I copy-pasted too fast. :-P

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're writing non-html to a document which should be html. As indicated by others, it may also be clearing your existing html. Instead of using `document.write`, you may want to append new elements to your document.

You can do that using the `document.createElement` function and `document.appendChild` function.

Here's what a quick Google search brought back:

http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the page to document which is overwriting all over your HTML.  Instead, write out the content to a DIV.

This should fix your background color problem as well.

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eQHj/2/) with an example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#F5F0EB";
var page = 0
function flip(){
document.getElementById("contentgoeshere").innerHTML=page;
page++;
}
</script>
<input type=button value="Next" onClick="flip()">
<div id="contentgoeshere">
</div>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As Mattias Buelens explained, `document.write` calls the `open` method, which clears the DOM, simply because -after loading- the `document.close` method is called automatically. There are a number of alternatives you can use, of course. 
Use the `innerHTML` attribute of the `body` element, for example.
Using `document.createElement` and `document.body.appendChild` is an option, too

But perhaps it's worth taking into consideration that both methods have their downsides: using `innerHTML` allows you to inject badly formatted markup into the DOM, and *could* leave you vulnerable to XSS attacks. 
Using `document.createElement` is slower (generally) and often requires more code, which in turn makes your script(s) less maintainable.

You could use something like this:

```
var flip = (function(tempDiv)
{//create a div once
    var page = 0,
    targetDiv = document.getElementById('contentgoeshere');//closure variables
    //page is now no longer an evil global, and the target element into which
    //we will inject new data is referenced, so we don't have to scan the DOM
    //on each function call
    return function(overridePage)//optional argument, just in case
    {//actual flip function is returned here
        overridePage = overridePage || page++;//new content
        tempDiv.innerHTML = overridePage;//render in div that isn't part of the DOM
        //any number of checks can go here, like:
        if (tempDiv.getElementsByTagName('script').length > 0)
        {
            alert('Naughty client, trying to inject your own scripts to my site');
            return;
        }
        targetDiv.innerHTML = tempDiv.innerHTML;
        //or, depending on your needs:
        targetDiv.innerHTML = tempDiv.innerText;//or the other way 'round
    };
}(document.createElement('div')));
```

A couple of side-notes: as it now stands, this function won't work because the DOM has to be fully loaded for the closure to work. A quick fix would be this:

```
var flip;//undefined
window.onload = function()
{
    flip = (function(tempDiv)
    {
        var page = 0,
        targetDiv = document.getElementById('contentgoeshere');
        return function(e)
        {
            tempDiv.innerHTML = e instanceof Event ? page++ : (e || page++);//ternary + logical or
            //your [optional] checks here
            targetDiv.innerHTML = tempDiv.innerHTML;
            if (e instanceof Event)
            {//this part is optional, but look it up if you want to: it's good stuff
                e.returnValue = false;
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                if (e.preventDefault)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
            return e;
        };
    }(document.createElement('div')));
    //instead of using the HTML onclick attribute:
    document.getElementById('buttonID').onclick = flip;//use as event handler
};
```

Note that `window.onload` causes memory leaks on IE<9, [check this link for the solution to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186750/memory-leak-risk-in-javascript-closures)