# Pause JavaScript function onclick

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hi I am new to JavaScript and AJAX.

The idea for this page is that when the user clicks the appropriate area in an image in a map it calls a JavaScript function *myFunction1* when the entry in 'field_X' is '0' - this function then updates 'field_X' to be '1' through AJAX ('field_X' starts with a '0' entry).

Then when the user next clicks the same area in the map *myFunction2* is called because the entry in 'field_X' is now '1' - and this then updates 'field_X' to be '2'.

And so on...

The AJAX call works fine and updates 'field_X' correctly when the appropriate function is called individually.

However the problem is (with the code as I have it) when the user clicks the map all 3 functions are called in succession straight away (and 'field_X' becomes '3'). I am not sure how to pause this between functions and wait for the next click by the user.

I have abbreviated the code in the functions as best I can as the functions do other things as well. Any help would be appreciated.

### PHP user page

```
<?php function request_data(){select field_X from TABLE_X; }  
$q = request_data(); ?>  

<map>  
<area onclick= <?php    
    if ($q == '0') {?>"myFunction1();" <?php }  
    if ($q == '1') {?>"myFunction2();" <?php }  
    if ($q == '2') {?>"myFunction3();" <?php }   
    if ($q == '3') { ...and so on... }   
?> />  
</map>
```

### JavaScript page

```
<script>   
//JavaScript  
function myFunction1() { update_1(); }  
function myFunction2() { update_2(); }  
function myFunction3() { update_3(); }  

//AJAX - abbreviated  
function update_1(){ update TABLE_X set field_X = (1); }  
function update_2(){ update TABLE_X set field_X = (2); }  
function update_3(){ update TABLE_X set field_X = (3); }  
</script>
```

Comment: share your markup and click event handler registration

Comment: Are these `update_X()` functions are server side or client side?

Comment: Set a global loading variable that prevents them from clicking the other spots until the ajax completes.

Comment: The request_data() function is PHP server side and the others are in a JavaScript page. The AJAX functions call functions that update the database and these are in a PHP page.

Comment: please post the _full_ JS code, your probably calling all functions in succession, because you're not taking the _asynchronous_ nature of ajax calls into account: use the `onreadystatechange` callback to call bind the next handler

Comment: Thanks @EliasVanOotegem for your help. Yes I did get some real help from some responses in my other posts and I have noted the gratitude in my responses but the tick does not always appear on the comment that was useful (am I missing something). Getting the question right is harder than it looks and sometimes no answers are posted probably because of this. I will go back and see if I can do this on those posts :)

Comment: Thanks @JohnVanDeWeghe yes this seems like what I am looking for - i will get into this in the morning and get back to you, thanks, Ted

Answer (score 2):

You can't pause JS's execution, not really... There are some hacky ways to do it, but they make for terrible code, so there really is no point in learning them. I would, as suggested by some in the comments use a global (or even better: a closure) variable. Here's a basic setup I would use in your case:

```
//server side, instead of echoing function1() etc...
echo 'var funcNumber = ';
switch($q)
{
    case 0: echo 1; break;
    case 1: echo 2; break;
    //and so on
}
echo ';';
//or better yet
echo 'var funcNumber  = '.($q + 1).';';
```

Then, in JS

```
//var funcNmber = 1; ===> makes it a global var, which is not recommended
window.onload = function()
{
    var funcNmber = 1;//echo here if possible
    var handler = function(e)
    {//assign to var, you'll see why
        var ajax = nex XMLHttpRequest(),
        that = this, //this points to the clicked element, reference it by var that
        queryString = 'field=' + funcNumber;
        //your basic setup
        //followed by this piece of magic:
        this.onclick = null;//unbind handler
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
            {//call complete
                funcNumber++;//increment
                that.onclick = handler;//rebind event handler, that's why we named it
            }
        };
    };
    document.getElementById('areaId').onclick = handler;//bind handler
};
```

Of course, this code needs a lot of work, still. If you want a X-browser XHTTP object, for example:

```
var getXHR = function()
{
    try
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            try
            {
                return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch(error)
            {
                throw new Error('no Ajax support?');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Also, since we're on X-browser stuff, note that `window.onload` can cause memory leaks, [which are quite easy to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186750/memory-leak-risk-in-javascript-closures) if you understand the way event delegation and closures work. Since you're relatively new to JS, I suspect you may want to read up on that... it is well worth it!

Comment: Thanks again @EliasVanOotegem for your help. I will have a go at this in morning - but yes this seems like the bit of the puzzle I have been missing. Many thanks, Ted