# Does using closure variables in click-functions always result in JavaScript memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures

Given this code:

```
function init() {

    var id = 1234;

    $("button").click(function() {
        alert(id);
    });

}
```

Basically when `init` is called it adds a `click` function on to the `button`.

Now lets say the `button` gets removed from the DOM somehow by external code. Normally, from what I understand, the *garbage collector* will check if the `click` function can be removed as well.

Will the *garbage collector* fail to remove the `click` function since the function is referencing the `id` variable via a closure, hence creating memory leak or will the `click` function be removed as well together with the DOM element?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried calling `init()` ten times to see the memory heap increasing, then I have removed the element to which I have attached the event with the `init()` function, and as you can see the memory heap does not go down.

[image]

---

I attempted again removing `alert(id)` from the event and the garbage collector worked this time.

[image]

Comment: So, it seems like it does result in memory leak. That's somewhat surprising though. Seems like this is a common pattern in JavaScript coding though, refereeing to a closure variable that is.

Comment: [I think that this could be of interested.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186750/memory-leak-risk-in-javascript-closures?rq=1)

Comment: There could be a chance that in order to garbage collector work you need to remove the events manually before removing the element.

Comment: Is it possible you can redo your test without the "alert" row that uses the "id"? Because I assume the click functions gets removed as well, if nothing  links to it, or it doesn't use any closure variables.

Comment: Just to confirm, without the reference it got cleared?

Comment: Yes. I have removed `alert(id)` and used `remove()` a second after attaching the events to the element instead of instantly after.

Comment: If this answer has answered your question, please remember to accept it @corgrath, thank you.